# How to convert strings containing only date and month into date format

Tags: javascript

I have `string` in below format:

```
 09Aug

 23Aug

 Sept27

 06Sep
```

How can I convert these `Strings` into proper `date` format? As I am not getting any `year` in above `string` so as a year I will consider current year
I did a lot of googles but couldn't found anything?

Comment: And there's no year or separator between days and months etc, just `09Aug`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: its not duplicate, I am getting the string in mentioned format only. So please don't downvote it

Comment: I don't think its possible to convert it without a year

Comment: @Preet, Is there anyway if I get year also

Comment: with year yes, first of all you have to change format of string like add spaces between day month then convert it

Comment: @Preet: I am not getting any separator else I could have done this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to separate the date and month, keep an array of valid months, then pass those numbers into `new Date`, something like

```js
function parseDate(d) {
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec']
  var date   = +d.replace(/\D/g,'');
  var mon    = months.indexOf( d.replace(/\d/g,'') );
  
  return new Date(2017, mon, date);
}

console.log( parseDate("09Aug") );
console.log( parseDate("23Aug") );
console.log( parseDate("Sept27") ); // why four letters ?
```

*(Note: dates are "local" in JS, so parsing them could result in differences, use UTC if important)*

Answer (score 0):

1) Concatenate current year to the string as :

```
var str1 = '09 Aug';
var str2 = ' '+(new Date()).getFullYear();
var res = str1.concat(str2);//outputs 09 Aug2017
new Date(res);//outputs Wed Aug 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```